# Determine Client to Server communication

Tags: browser

I'm trying to do some troubleshooting on some servers.

I want to know how to determine the client to server communication between my browser and a specific server.

So essentially I want to see what my browser is doing with the server and what the server is doing with my browser.

Also how can I find when cookies are created by the requests with the server in my browser.

Comment: Please understand that **Questions must be relevant to [professional system administration](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity).** Server Fault is a site dedicated to professional sysadmins; novice questions are off-topic as are questions related to home or personal use scenarios. Please see the [Help Center](http://serverfault.com/help)  for more information on topicality.  I've asked that the question be moved to SuperUser.com for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Internet Explorer have a developer mode built into them. You access this by hitting F12.In the developer options you can select network and see client to server communication. For more information on developer mode for these two browsers, you can check out the links below. I find that if I just want to monitor communication or inspect elements, it's quicker to use the built in tools rather than fire up Wire Shark or fiddler.

IE:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85)

Chrome:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I will be sure to use that too. I do like fiddler though its really a nifty piece of kit.

Comment: I like Fiddler if I am having to monitor SSL traffic as they have the certificate you can install and view the traffic unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a packet sniffer (like Wireshark), or an HTTP proxy (like Fiddler on Windows.) Either will show you the requests, answers, and things like cookies and other headers.

Comment: Would something like firebug do the trick?

Comment: Taking a quick look, I don't believe so. That's more of an HTML/CSS/JS debugger. I don't think that it shows the HTTP traffic in the same way as you're requesting. At any rate, this site is not intended for explicit product recommendations, but I answered with examples because you didn't seem to know what kinds of technology to look for.

Comment: OK - way down on the feature list of firebug is HTTP Status Codes and HTTP Headers, so it might do some or all of what you want. Give it a shot, it's free. Try the others; they're free too.

Comment: Thank you so much, Im downloading wireshark now, to describe a bit more I've been given a web page by a friend and hes asked me to this, "Can you please describe the client to server communication between your browser and "name of server here" server?

Comment: A friend? this sounds like homework. Please read the "help" link at the top of the site to understand what questions should, and shouldn't, be asked here.

Comment: This isn't home work..... Im a Biologist. :)

Comment: Well, good luck.

Comment: @Code in the future you should stick with SuperUser.com instead for your questions.  It's the right site.